# jQuery UI sortable flickering and jumping around when dragging items - connected lists

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two connected lists, however when dragging items around trying to place them, the sortable jumps and flickerings all over the place, making it really hard to order the items. This resulting in a really bad user experience.

Is there are solution for this?

I have a full demo with all the code below, just cant figure out how to stop the flickering and make it a nice smooth experience!

http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/62/

Tried overflow below on the container div but no such luck!

```
overflow:visible;
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: did you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to display items in the ADDED AREA in the grid and update behavior like [this](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid). Each item should have same size whatever its content. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Items are all going to be different sizes due to the text being different inside the li's. You could get 1 word then in another you could get a really long string of characters.